# AWS SDK v3 error handling - can't use instanceof with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, aws-sdk-js

I've used AWS SDK for JavaScript before a lot, but in the past I've always used the v2 patterns. I'm trying for the first time to use the modular v3 approach. For error handling, I'm following [this guide](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/service-error-handling-modular-aws-sdk-js/).

Here's my code:

```
import { DynamoDB, ConditionalCheckFailedException } from '@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb';
const db = new DynamoDB({region: 'us-east-1'});
try {
    const result = await db.putItem({
        TableName: myTable,
        Item: myItem,
        ConditionExpression: 'attribute_not_exists(PK)',
    });
    console.log("Inserted");
} catch (ex) {
    if(ex instanceof ConditionalCheckFailedException) {
        console.log("Already exists");
    }
    throw ex;
}
```

But unfortunately TypeScript is not happy with this:

> The right-hand side of an 'instanceof' expression must be of type 'any' or of a type assignable to the 'Function' interface type. `ts(2359)`

The AWS blog post specifically mentions TypeScript, so I expect that there's some way to make this work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have a similar problem. In lightsail-client when a static IP is not found, It throws LightsailServiceException instead of NotFoundException and instanceof is useless because LightsailServiceException is the base exception. Unfortunately, I resorted to checking by the the name property.

Answer (score 0):

In [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/index.html#troubleshooting), they give this example code:

```
try {
  const data = await client.send(command);
  // process data.
} catch (error) {
  const { requestId, cfId, extendedRequestId } = error.$$metadata;
  console.log({ requestId, cfId, extendedRequestId });
  /**
   * The keys within exceptions are also parsed.
   * You can access them by specifying exception names:
   * if (error.name === 'SomeServiceException') {
   *     const value = error.specialKeyInException;
   * }
   */
}
```

So I presume that this would work in place of `instanceof`:

`if (error.name === 'ConditionalCheckFailedException') { }`

Comment: That's the old way of doing things, the article I linked shows it and says that you can now use `instanceof` instead.

The issue for me was far simpler (and more embarassing). I was using `@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb` v3.18.0, and support for instanceof was added in v3.53.0. I updated to v3.142.0 and it worked perfectly afterwards.